# How to Download a file to a specific path in the server : Python

Tags: python, jython

How to download a file through http on to a local folder on my server in jython(or python)

The below code might work

```
os.chdir("/path/to/change/to")
from urllib2 import urlopen
f = urlopen("http://some.server/some/directory/some.file")
```

But for this my Current working directory is changed.I want to be in the current working directory and download the file to any given path on my Server.

Any help ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve)

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('http://python.org/images/python-logo.gif', '/tmp/foo.gif')
```

Comment: @whokares: Using `shutil.copy()` ? You should `import shutil`, but `urllib.urlretrieve()` do everything for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `open(..., 'wb')` to open the file where you like, `urllib2.urlopen()` to open the network resource, and [`shutil.copyfileobj()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj) to copy from one to the other.

Comment: Why do I have to create a local file and then read into it,Cant I download a file as is from a given pah and place it on the server. ?Why do u need shutil.copyfileobj() btw ?

Comment: I thin k the below one works                               shutil.copy(src, dst)¶
    Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory, a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in the directory specified. Permission bits are copied. src and dst are path names given as strings.