# How to download files from Scraped Links[python] without logging in to a specified directory

Tags: python, web, download, text-mining, url-encoding

[How to Download PDFs from Scraped Links [Python]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29641671/how-to-download-pdfs-from-scraped-links-python)

After working on this I was stuck with the following issues 
Is it possible to download if my college portal has a login page and if yes what should be added to this...
Can this be fixed

Comment: You can try logging in using requests, selenium or something similar

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you should use something like Selenium. This library will allow you to run a browser and navigate through coding, just like you would. You will be able [to fill out the username and password forms and click the submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186327/fill-username-and-password-using-selenium-in-python), and log in to the website. [Check out this guide about web scraping and the Selenium library](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter11)

If you find Selenium too slow, a faster alternative is [Mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/). The problem is that it does not process Javascript, and this will break some webpages.